# Variation of Pontryagin density $*R^{abcd}R_{abcd}$ with respect to inverse metric $g^{ab}$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

I am computing the variation of $*R^{abcd}R_{abcd}$ with respect to inverse metric $g^{ab}$, where $R^{abcd}$ is Riemann tensor and $*R^{abcd}$ is its dual. I hope to express the result in terms of some known tensors,e.g., Riemann tensor.

Is this a known result? any reference?